# R-Studio Package Installation Error

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install and read different packages into R-Studio and I face the same error every time. I am not sure what is causing the problem and I would appreciate it if someone can provide some insights into this..The following is the error message:

```
install.packages("dplyr")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/eliew/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘bindr’, ‘assertthat’, ‘bindrcpp’, ‘glue’, ‘magrittr’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘rlang’, ‘R6’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘tibble’, ‘BH’, ‘plogr’


trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/dplyr_0.7.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2885453 bytes (2.8 MB)
downloaded 2.8 MB

package ‘bindr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c6b34a6c\bindr’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\bindr’

package ‘assertthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c389f2e27\assertthat’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\assertthat’

package ‘bindrcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c4c4a15af\bindrcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\bindrcpp’

package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c2f503588\glue’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\glue’

package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘pkgconfig’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c7f6e32c9\rlang’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rlang’

package ‘R6’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c3b3c3540\R6’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\R6’
package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c6f642de\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\Rcpp’

package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c326d2efb\tibble’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\tibble’

package ‘BH’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

package ‘plogr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c697ff4d\plogr’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\plogr’

package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file316c1ea2f5b\dplyr’ to ‘C:\Users\eliew\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\dplyr’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\eliew\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWkewty\downloaded_packages

 library("dplyr")

Error in library("dplyr") : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
```

Comment: Change your directory permissions so that your R library directory (listed in the output) is writable. Or set your library to a different location. Or, as a quick hack, run R in administrator mode and try reinstalling.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did try to run as administrator, but in the error messages, it kept showing "trying URL" from cran.rstudio.com. One example would be "trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/bindr_0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 14968 bytes (14 KB)
downloaded 14 KB". It keeps doing this, I wish I can post the entire error but I am not allowed to post multiple URLs here..

Comment: That's not an error, just an informational message.

Comment: I see.. now that I am running as an admin, I am getting this: The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\eliew\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWKo9nu\downloaded_packages
> library("dplyr")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rlang’

Comment: I would `remove.packages("dplyr")` and start over.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work..

Comment: Can you update your question with all of the things you are currently during and the current error message(s)? And also include the output of `sessionInfo()` and `.libPaths()`?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue . To resolve this add line trace(utils:::unpackPkgZip, edit=TRUE)
then change line from source Sys.sleep(0.5) to Sys.sleep(2.5). clicked on save
Refer : http://rampradeeppakalapati.blogspot.com/2018/02/r-studio-warning-unable-to-move.html

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, one must run RStudio in Administrator mode to install packages in the default R subdirectories. To run RStudio in Administrator mode, right click on the RStudio icon in Windows, and select *Run as Administrator* from the popup menu.

Comment: It's better, if possible, to make your library directory writable under the normal user role so that you don't accidentally run malicious code in administrator mode.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Now that I am running as an admin, I am getting this: The downloaded binary packages are in C:\Users\eliew\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWKo9nu\downloaded_pac‌​kages > library("dplyr") Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘rlang’

Comment: How do I make my library directory writable? Sorry, if this is a stupid question. I am not familiar with R at all..

Comment: @EugeniaLiew - use `install.packages("rlang")` to install `rlang`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved for me when I followed @Thomas' suggestion and unchecked "read only" within properties of my ~Documents/R/win-library/3.4 folder.